# AWS Lambda unable to import module from layer

Tags: python, lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I am trying to create a Lambda function with a dependency to load from a layer. I thought I had this working when I deployed it a while ago, but I keep getting this error now, and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong here.

I am trying to create a layer with pyopenssl for python 3.x. My understanding is that the dependencies should be installed into a "python" top level directory before being zipped for the layer. Here is how the layer is created:

requirements.txt:

```
$ echo "pyopenssl" > requirements.txt
pip install -t python -r requirements.txt
python -c "import shutil;shutil.make_archive('layer-openssl','zip','python')"
```

The python command is the equivalent of creating a zip file from the `python` directory. e.g. if I create a temp directory and unzip in there, the top level directory is `python` with `OpenSSL` and all the transitive dependencies in it (cffi, cryptography, etc).

Python version is 3.8, and pip is 20.0 from python 3.8 too.

I then create the layer (e.g. for testing at the moment, I am doing this manually in the web console) - have marked the layer as compatible with 3.6, 3.7 and 3.8 versions.

Then I create a Python 3.8 function, and add an import:

```
from OpenSSL.crypto import load_certificate

def lambda_handler(event, context):
  return true
```

And this gives me an error: `Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named OpenSSL.crypto`

I have tried publishing a 2nd version of the layer marked as compatible with Python 2.7, and then created a 2.7 runtime function with the same import, but it fails too.

Is there anything obvious that I am doing wrong that I am missing? Should adding OpenSSL to `python` be sufficient - i am pretty sure i had this working with python 3.8 a short while ago, and am using the same deployment code on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The loading works if I add a variable of `PYTHONPATH` set to `/opt` to the lambda. It looks like "/opt/python" is not searched by default.

Not sure how it worked previously